# How do I upload and encode video to multiple formats in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am making a video sharing website using Django, and I would like to know how would I encode the video to other formats that browsers support after uploading? I don't want to use any other Django apps to do this.

Comment: `ffmpeg`, not sure of its licensing, though...

Comment: I know about ffmpeg, I just need to know how I would signal Django to start the encoding process.

Comment: you could call it from python in `subproccess` or you could look for a pythong ffmpeg wrapper.  This could also introduce need for some sort of job queue/offline batching so the webserver doesn't have to wait on the conversion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: @dm03514, thank you, I think I could try `Celery` for the queuing, but I wouldn't really know very well.